# How do I aggregate datetime data by week using isocalendar in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to aggregate datetime data to a weekly level.  The following works with `dt.week`, but I receive a warning that `dt.week` has been deprecated.  I have not had success with isocalendar yet.  What would you recommend?

Here is an example of the data I would like to aggregate by week:

```
import pandas as pd
times = ['2021-01-28 08:00:00', '2021-01-26 08:00:00', '2021-01-25 08:00:00']
quantities = [40, 12, 43]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-28 08:00:00','2021-01-26 08:00:00','2021-02-25 08:00:00'],
                   'quantity':[40, 12, 43]}) # 52 in one week, 43 in the other week
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df
```

The `dt.week` method works, but throws a warning:

```
df['week_num'] = df['date'].dt.week
df.groupby('week_num').sum('quantity')
```

Result: **week_num 4** has a **quantity of 52** and **week_num 8** has a **quantity of 43**.

The warning reads `<ipython-input-50-d66026a79596>:1: FutureWarning: Series.dt.weekofyear and Series.dt.week have been deprecated.  Please use Series.dt.isocalendar().week instead. df['week_num'] = df['date'].dt.week`

Comment: you mention having "not had success with `isocalendar()`". How so? What happens if you try to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just follow and try what it says:

```py
>>> df.groupby(df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week).sum('quantity')
      quantity
week          
4           52
8           43
```

or, if you prefer `week_num`:

```py
df.groupby(
    df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week
).sum('quantity').rename_axis(index='week_num')
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works.  I must have mistyped or misread.  This output is even better than the deprecated version!